Can a weapon with a Shifting Rune transform into a tool (i.e. an Improvised Weapon)
For example, could I turn a 1-handed Shifting weapon into a Crowbar, or a lockpick, or a shovel?

No.
The Shifting rune states:

With a moment of manipulation, you can shift this weapon into a different weapon with a similar form.
...For example, a bastard sword requires one hand, even though it gets a benefit in two hands from the two-hand trait. Therefore, a shifting bastard sword could turn into a longsword, but not a greatsword. (Emphasis mine)

Tools like a set of lockpicks or a shovel are too drastically different in form. If a bastard sword can't turn into a greatsword, I'd rule even a club is too far away from a crowbar.
Finally, Tools are also not weapons. They are only improvised weapons while you're attacking with them:

If you attack with something that wasn’t built to be a weapon, such as a chair or a vase, you’re making an attack with an improvised weapon. (Emphasis mine)


A pick (the weapon) is more similar to the pick (the tool) than to a shortsword, still only the second is legal. Similarity has nothing to do with it

@András Sort of. I'm going to come back to this answer: the important part is actually just tools not being weapons. Turns out the similarity language is almost exclusively about how many hands you use to wield the weapon and doesn't matter as much. Either way, the answer is still No.
